# Xamarin.Forms UI Testing- Timed out waiting for keyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

After Selecting *Hardware->Keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard* still its not working.

> Error while performing EnterText(Marked("Password"), "asdfg")
>   Exception: System.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for keyboard.
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.WaitForHelper.WaitFor (System.Func 1[TResult]
>   predicate, System.String timeoutMessage, System.Nullable 1[T] timeout,
>   System.Nullable 1[T] retryFrequency, System.Nullable 1[T] postTimeout)
>   [0x000ff] in <40cdba9629c64993881ff8259cae4300>:0
>   at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+c__AnonStorey6.<>m__0 ()
>   [0x00165] in <40cdba9629c64993881ff8259cae4300>:0
>   at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With (System.Action func,
>   System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x00006] in
>   <40cdba9629c64993881ff

Comment: Is this happening sometimes or always?

Comment: It's happening for me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me I had to reset the sim. It was happening frequently until I upgraded to xcode 9.

Comment: I'm wondering, could you elaborate what is the sim in simulator?

Comment: @PavloDatsiuk sim is shorthand for simulator I don't understand what your question?